# Formula for vehicle shortest path between two points with angle, considering vehicle factors?

Tags: problem-solving, curves

It was hard to be too descriptive in the title, so here is what I'm looking for: A formula, if it exists, for finding the shortest path from A to B (2D), including angle, but it must consider minimum turning radius.

What I have tried:
Other than online searching, I am currently running a computer simulation I made, featuring vehicles with various turning radii, trying different scenarios. My current line of thinking is to have the vehicle turn towards the desired angle as tight as possible, and at a threshold, taper the steering back in the other direction until the angle matches up at the right spot.

In addition to this, there are two scenarios I am still unsure as to how they may fit into such a formula (if possible):

Reaching a point INSIDE my minimum turning radius as fast. Right now my best guess it to turn in the opposite direction from the desired angle, and at some certain point, turn hard towards the angle to meet the minimum steering radius and the do the same as what I mentioned above.

Providing leeway for position/angle error for real world scenarios, which would definitely not be able to perfectly match the shortest path. For this I thought about trying to enlarge the minimum steering radius to account for potential error in position locating devices, but I'm not sure if that is the correct line of thinking.

So to sum it up, I want a formula to get a vehicle at a certain position and angle to another position and another angle in as short distance as possible, while possibly allowing for error and destinations within the minimum steering radius.

Comment: Do you want a solution composed by an arc of a circle and a segment, or a curve having a continuously varying curvature?

Comment: I apologize for the late response. Continuously varying curvature is what I envision, though I am open to other options.